# MYSQL populate data using loop

Tags: php, mysql

I am a begineer in mysql.

I have a task. There are 3 tables

**purchase_master**

```
"autoid","user_id","package_id"
```

**user_master**

```
"autoid","user_id","name","user_email","user_pass"
```

**package_master**

```
"poster_path","overview","release_date","genre_ids","package_id","original_title"
```

My requirement is that purchase_master table should be populated such that it contains all packages from `package_master` against every user from `user_master`.

e.g., if there are 10 users in `user_master` and 10 packages in `package_master`, so the `purchase_master` will have 100 rows (10 user * 10 packages). So each user has all 10 packages.

I dont have any clue how to do it in mysql, else I have to find a way to do this in PHP via looping.

Comment: Fetch all data of users and packages.. and loop it to populate data using php

Comment: Fetch all data from both tables and use `foreach` [loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to populate your `purchase_master` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
INSERT INTO purchase_master ("user_id","package_id")
  SELECT um."user_id", pm."package_id"
  FROM user_master as um
  JOIN package_master as pm
```

Hope this helps

Documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html